# Joomla 2.5 - Saving items and content, added with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla, save

I am working on a module in Joomla right now, where I need to add dynamically an basically infinite amount of new "fieldblocks" to the module frontend (Administrator > Extensions > Modules > myModule ).

Each fieldblock contains several form-items  (text, checkbox, select, radio, etc..)

I solved this by using JavaScript (jQuery) and an custom form field type which works just fine, but I have a bit of an issue by saving the content and the fieldblocks.

So my Question is: is there any possibility to save any number of fieldblocks with its contents? And if there is a solution, please tell me how!

[Link to a Screenshot](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/51/agwa.png/)

Comment: Joomla automatically saves standard module parameters in the database. As for custom fields, what you can do is use a hidden field that all the values of your custom fields append to, and then then hidden field is what actually gets saved.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Still it was not quite satisfying.

If there is no other chance, to handle with this problem, i have to look for another method.

Cheers.